# Do we want questions about conventions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I've been examining some tags and saw that in the [conventions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conventions) tag, we have exactly 3 questions, all of them are closed (2 as off-topic, one as too broad).

Now the questions themselves weren't that 100% great, but the question is, are convention questions on topic at all? If so, what isn't on-topic, and what is? Do we want any questions about conventions?

Comment: Doe we have any experts on conventions here that can answer such questions? I know I can't

Comment: If we're going to accept [questions on anime clubs](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2852), conventions also seem like a natural topic as well. (Admittedly, the topicality of clubs is also debatable, which is partly why I'm bringing it up.) It may be hard in practice to come up with a good question for this site on this topic though.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if somebody who knows stuff about conventions would post some example questions as answers here so that we can evaluate their topicality.

Answer (score 2):

I think that we should keep an open mind on the topic, but at the same time better define the scope of these questions (which comes down to objectivity and subjectivity, the location of the poster, and interests [cosplay, doujinshi, VN, etc]). The 1st question about AMVs is off topic due to being more of a legal question, of which we have no expertise in (unless someone here is secretly or is planning to be a bar certified copyright lawyer). The second one about cosplay is considered to be a recommendation question (thus off-topic). The third one was deem to be too broad, but also very opinion-based.

### Think about your audience

Think about what type of people you want to use the site. While we don't necessarily want subjective question and answer on which anime convention is the best, some more objectified question like what the largest anime/manga convention in X country can be helpful for people just getting into the anime and manga subculture.

### Think about the topic

Question not on the specific topics of the events of the venue, but more about the venue locations like: "I'm going to X convention, what are some ways I can get to the site via Y mode of transportation?" should be off topic. Question about the events and topics might be more appropriate.

"What are the major attractions/events/speakers of Z convention?," or "Who illustrated the catalog for Q convention?"

Comment: So if I asked for example: What is the largest convention in Australia?, would that be on topic Just wondering on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that we should consider them at least. Although the questions we had so far were pretty low quality, there might also be some questions worth while such as

- 1) Questions regarding convention rules

not all conventions follow the same rule sets, and some rules can be pretty well hidden on sites. For example at Animecon it is not permitted to carry large props, which is quite the ambiguous rule. And no more clarification is given until you buy a ticket. Personally I don't think allot of unique questions will be found, as in most cases the answer can be found on the site it self, but there might be some unique ones like the one mentioned.

- 2) Questions regarding the clarification of certain events.

Lots of events happen at cons. Including off course the Cosplay competitions, concerts And the likes. Asking questions such as "Is it okay to do a echii cosplay for the competition?" or "How does the cosplay competition actually work?" Would in my opinion  be worth while.

- 3) Questions regarding availability.

This is a pretty broad topic, and can be seen from availability of hotel/motels/public transport near the con, to the availability of for example dressing rooms for potential change of cos-playing clothes.

I also think if we start accepting those kind of questions allot of potentially unwanted questions might also pop up

- 4) Questions regarding the program.

Programs change, it's simple as that. Besides the fact that its usually marked on the site, its a future event we do not know of till announced. I think those should be handle like when will xxx start airing and be closed as announced future events.

- 5) Questions regarding meet-ups

Fair chance will be that there will be questions about planning meet ups. Less likely but there chances are still there. I think those kinda questions should be handled as off topic

Overall I think we should accept questions regarding conventions. Personally I don't think there will be allot of traffic on the site regarding conventions, and if there is we most likely want to judge them on a individual basis as some might prove to be valuable questions.